# JS function not getting dropdown text

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown form that I have created - I need to have the dropdown either be auto-generated to a text box once selected or have it placed in the text box once a button has been pressed. For example "Get Hex"

Here is my dropdown:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Logos</legend>
  <p>
    <label>Choose Desired Logo</label>
    <select id = "Logo">
      <option value = "00">Holden</option>
      <option value = "01">HSV</option>
      <option value = "02">Chevrolet</option>
      <option value = "02">Chevrolet</option>
      <option value = "04">CSV</option>
      <option value = "05">Pontiac</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Show Hex" onclick="displaySelectedItem(val);" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="Logo" />
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

And here is the last JS script i've tried. I have tried a few but I am surely missing something as nothing I command works.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function displaySelectedItem(val)
{
  alert(val);
}
//-->
</script>
```

So I need for the text box to contain the hex code in the `<option value = "##">`

I'll be using this throughout 6 different forms, all needing the same thing.

Comment: I would put the onclick event on the select-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="button" value="Show Hex" onclick="displaySelectedItem(val);" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Show Hex" onclick="displaySelectedItem(document.getElementById('Logo').value);" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DP5nw/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DP5nw/1/  --- Here is the updated example with what he wanted, which is `get the value of select and put into input` but @Neolisk edited the question and removed that part of what he asked.

Comment: That worked, for the most part. Haha. Why did it do a pop up and not generate to the text field below, as seen in the example?

Comment: I justed used the alert because you did. You can remove it and change it to `document.getElementById('Logo2').value = val;` (note that IDs muct be unique and in your example you re-used "Logo"). See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DP5nw/2/

Comment: http://www.757goat.org/gto_cluster/Worksheettestjs.php - In the jsfiddle it works perfectly, but in IE and Chrome it results in a popup box. Is this due to something i've commanded??
Edit: This is a link to the document i'm working on. It's a plain jane test site

Comment: Yes it should, although without seeing all your code I can't say with 100% certainty.

Comment: I tested it - what I see is that when I select get hex it puts it in the year2 dropdown now: I used 
function displaySelectedItem(val){
    document.getElementById('year2').value = val;
} 
under the first script and

<input type="button" value="Show Hex" onclick="displaySelectedItem(document.getElementById('year').value);" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="year2" />
    </p>

Ideally i'd like to be able to call all of those tables by one "Get Hex" button and have them all displayed on one line

Comment: If you go back to the link I posted you'll see what I mean

Comment: I only see one hex dropdown on the link you posted. Why'd you unaccept the answer? Is something wrong with it?

Comment: I hit the wrong thing on my phone, sorry for any confusion. I'll respond to your last post once I get back to a pc. Thanks for the help, its much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.757goat.org/gto_cluster/Worksheettestjs.php

Ok - if you go there you will see the first two dropdowns have 'show hex' next to the selection. It doesn't matter which one you click - it shows it in the second blank table

Comment: You're defining the same function twice. You'll need to modify the function (get rid of the other) to accept two parameters, the value to display and the ID of the input to display it in. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pttYJ/

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Or how can I have them output all of the data in a series to one output box? (logo,year,shutdowntext etc. on one line)

Comment: You need to start a new question that describes exactly what you need. This one has changed too much.